# How to validate fields of own fields in JSF?

Tags: java, validation, jsf, java-ee-6, bean-validation

It sounds strange. But i need to validate the field Adress of Company in Person entity. 
Company is a field of Person and Addres is afield of Company.

I want to validate the address of Company in Person entity.

Why?? Because The company should have an address if i use it in a Person entity not before?

How can I implement this validation??

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = Constants.DB_SCHEMA)
public class Person{
   Company company;

  // Validation of the address should come here ???
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = Constants.DB_SCHEMA)
public class Company{
   String address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do that with the annotation @NotNull on the address attribute of your Company class.

But: Your current code won't work anyway because you have not specified the relation between the classes and you don't have primary keys....

Here is an example how it could work:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Company company;

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }    
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String adress;

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: If Person is the aggregate root, you should add '@Valid' on the company property of the Person class. Otherwise the Company class didn't get validated.